# Brostrend wifi dongle installation

Tags: wireless

I am trying to install a Brostrend ac1200 dual band Wifi dongle for Linux systems on an old hp pc running ubuntu server 16.04 LTS. As a starter on Linux systems I managed to find and install the driver on command line after several days. My problem now is that the system does not associate the wifi dongle with any network interface, hence it's sitting in the usb port idle. How do I bring it alive?

Comment: Hi, I'm using it as a learning tool, will upgrade to a more recent OS after a month. thanks

Comment: Hi all , thanks for viewing or trying to help. I have upgraded to ubuntu server 18.04 and managed to download drivers from command line for the wifi dongle and it worked for a short time but stopped after some upgrades.